# Is it possible to use custom markers?

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe

Is it possible to use bespoke markers that do not resemble the "Hiro" marker like below. Could I potentially use a random shape (a solid red oval for example) as a marker?

If this is not currently supported, could someone point me into the right direction to where I might start building this functionality?

[image]

Comment: **Ensure that your marker PNG file does not contains any transparency**. The .patt generated file won't be OK & your printed marker won't be detected.

Answer (score 9):

[AR.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js) supports custom markers. 
Make any silly image with the [marker generator](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html).

Let ar.js know that you want to use your marker:

```
<a-marker type="pattern" url="patterns/mypattern.patt">
      <a-entity myobject></a-entity>
</a-marker>
```

and voila. You can check it out in this [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/custommarker-ar) using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkmkk.jpg) image.

Comment: Is this still up to date? because it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Blinxen last time i checked, there was a bug in ar.js, and found a solution here https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/216#issuecomment-346906569. I'll add it to the anwser

Comment: I cloned the ar.js master branch and made the changes to the file, but when I open the html, I get a refference error for both file on some random lines. It just showes a blank page.

Comment: @Blinxen i'll try it out in ~3h

Comment: Ok, but please clone the master branch, so we have the same git repo and try it. Thank you.

Comment: @Blinxen i've been trying to make it work, check out my update

Comment: @Blinxen: see my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

**1. preset="pattern"**

Firstly, if you look at the raw js script: https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js, you'll notice there is no `preset="custom"` in the `else if`. For example, search `else if( _this.data.preset === 'kanji' ){`.

There is however a `preset="pattern"`. So ignore the documentation and set `preset="pattern"` For example:

`<a-marker preset="pattern" type="pattern" url="img/pattern-marker.patt">
   <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='color: black;' soundhandler></a-box>
 </a-marker>`

**2. Upload .patt to your GitHub so it can resolve the file**

Secondly, my .patt wasn't being picked up locally, so `url="img/pattern-marker.patt"` may not work. Push this `.patt` file up to GitHub and then reference it using the raw.githubusercontent.

**Example**

You can test this using my pattern. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lbelfield/augmented-reality/master/src/components/trainTicket/train-ticket.patt.

The image of the marker is below:
https://github.com/lbelfield/augmented-reality/blob/master/src/components/trainTicket/train-ticket.png

**React-Web-AR:**
This won't be applicable for you, but if anyone is using React-Web-AR like myself, use this:

`<Marker parameters={{ 
preset: 'pattern',
type: 'pattern', 
patternUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lbelfield/augmented-reality/master/src/components/trainTicket/train-ticket.patt', 
url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lbelfield/augmented-reality/master/src/components/trainTicket/train-ticket.patt' 
}}>`

Comment: +1 way more thorough :). Something must have change in the recent build, since it works just like i described it in the very beginning ( You don't need the `preset="pattern" `)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** First, make a custom marker by visiting [this page](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html)

**Step 2:** Place the downloaded pattern ( from the above link ) to your root directory or upload it to your server

**Step 3:** Copy-paste the below code

```
 <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;'>
    <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;'></a-box>
    <a-marker-camera preset='custom' type='pattern' url='PATH_TO_DOWNLOADED_PATTERN'></a-marker-camera>
    <a-entity myobject></a-entity>
    </a-marker>
</a-scene>
```