# How to create custom marker in Ar.js?

Tags: javascript, aframe, ar.js

I Was wondering how things work in Ar.js , But i was stuck with
creating custom Markers and custom shapes , is there any way to
customize things.

this is What i have got things to getting started.

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<!-- include ar.js for A-Frame -->
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
  <a-scene embedded arjs>
    <!-- create your content here. just a box for now -->
    <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;'></a-box>
    <!-- define a camera which will move according to the marker position -->
    <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

This is simple example for getting started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create & specify a custom pattern file.
See [Is it possible to use bespoke markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820170/is-it-possible-to-use-bespoke-markers/45823557#45823557)

You should also remove the hiro preset.

Comment: Thanks That is the solution

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [marker generator](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html).

In the marker generator

- Upload your image .
- Download the trained marker.
- Include it in your Code.

The trained marker is contained in a `.patt` file.
This file contains the encoded marker that you should reuse in your code. You specify you want a pattern marker and you provide the URL to your own marker. So just replace this in your code.

```
<a-marker-camera preset='custom' type='pattern' url='assets/NAME-OF-PATTERN-FILE.patt'></a-marker-camera>
```