# How to get detect multiple markers with AR.js

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am trying to detect different markers. One is a pattern named and1painting.patt and the other is the preset 'hiro'

When I show the hiro pattern, it is detected by the and1painting.patt marker. E.g. in the following code, it always shows the blue box rather than red, when I show the hiro marker. Thoughts on why? I tried this with the sample1.patt that is already in the repo but it didn't work either.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"> </script>
  <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;'>
        <a-marker type='pattern' patternUrl='Data/and1painting.patt'>
            <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5; side:double; color:blue;'>
            </a-box>
        </a-marker>
        <!-- handle marker with hiro preset -->
        <a-marker preset='hiro'>
            <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5; side:double; color:red;'>
            </a-box>
        </a-marker>
        <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check out if the custom marker works without the hiro marker in your code, if not, try another build like i described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820170/is-it-possible-to-use-bespoke-markers

Comment: I tried it with one of the other markers that comes with AR.js -- 'sample1.patt' and it doesn't work. It only works if I use <a-marker preset='kanji'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately AR.JS still is seriously broken at the moment:
https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/pull/236

You can hack your way to a working solution, if you follow the comments in the issue.

Comment: Seems like this is it. I had assumed from the 'merged' comment that it was fixed. Perhaps needs to be forked if original dev isn't able to keep up with it. Super useful library

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ar.js is not at all that broken. There is a syntax error in the code above and that is the reason it doesn't work. The correct syntax of the call for the pattern file is simply 'url = ' instead of 'patternUrl = ''.

Try this:

a-marker type='pattern' url='Data/and1painting.patt'

I know it works, because it took me forever to figure it out.