# AR.JS custom marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, aframe, ar.js

I'm trying to use a custom marker for AR.JS. However after following the directions to create a custom marker and then change the marker presets, it still doesn't work. Any ideas on how to properly implement?

```
<a-marker preset="custom" type="pattern" url="img/pattern-marker.patt">
   <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='color: black;' soundhandler></a-box>
 </a-marker>
```

Is this not correct implementation in the marker? For reference, I used a very simple b/w circular image to test and it still did not work. Is there some other code that needs to be written to register a custom marker pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use bespoke markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820170/is-it-possible-to-use-bespoke-markers)

Answer (score 2):

I've spent ages on this! Finally figured out it is a couple of problems.

**1. preset="pattern"**

Firstly, if you look at the raw js script: https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js, you'll notice there is no `preset="custom"` in the `else if`. For example, search `else if( _this.data.preset === 'kanji' ){`.

There is however a `preset="pattern"`. So in your example, replace:

`<a-marker preset="custom" type="pattern" url="img/pattern-marker.patt">
   <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='color: black;' soundhandler></a-box>
 </a-marker>`

with

`<a-marker preset="pattern" type="pattern" url="img/pattern-marker.patt">
   <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='color: black;' soundhandler></a-box>
 </a-marker>`

**2. Upload .patt to your GitHub so it can resolve the file**

Secondly, my .patt wasn't being picked up locally, so `url="img/pattern-marker.patt"` won't work. Push this `.patt` file up to GitHub and then reference it using the raw.githubusercontent.

**Example**

You can test this using my pattern. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lbelfield/augmented-reality/master/src/components/trainTicket/train-ticket.patt.

The image of the marker is below:
https://github.com/lbelfield/augmented-reality/blob/master/src/components/trainTicket/train-ticket.png

**React-Web-AR:**
This won't be applicable for you, but if anyone is using React-Web-AR like myself, use this:

`<Marker parameters={{ 
preset: 'pattern',
type: 'pattern', 
patternUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lbelfield/augmented-reality/master/src/components/trainTicket/train-ticket.patt', 
url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lbelfield/augmented-reality/master/src/components/trainTicket/train-ticket.patt' 
}}>`

Comment: Has this worked out for you?  I tried creating markers based on business cards and it didnt work.  Even if you tried "scanning" the physical train ticket, it wont work because it is looking for the border.