# How do I use Custom Marker with ar.js

Tags: javascript, html, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am trying to make a custom marker work in ar.js, sadly with no succes, was hoping somebody could help.

I have tried all of those guides:
https://medium.com/@aschmelyun/so-you-want-to-get-started-with-ar-js-41dd4fba5f81
https://medium.com/arjs/how-to-create-your-own-marker-44becbec1105
https://katharine.org/tutorials/custom-markers-ar-js/

Sadly it does not seem to work. weirdly enough, with the hiro Marker it still worked, eventhough the code doesn't mention it... (I tried editing the .js file for the katherine-tutorial only).

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <script src="aframe.min.js"></script>            
  <script src="aframe-ar.js"></script>            
<script src="aframe-gif-shader.js"></script>   

  <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">    
    <a-scene embedded arjs="debugUIEnabled: false">  
      <a-assets> 
        <img id="asset" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader/master/examples/basic/banana.gif">
      </a-assets>
      <a-marker preset='custom' type="pattern" url='testpattern.patt'> 
      <a-entity geometry="primitive:plane;width:2;height:2;"
      position="0 0 0"
      rotation="-90 0 0"
      scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"
      material="shader:gif;src:#asset;alphaTest:0.5;"></a-entity>
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>    
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Also I have a problem with, when i upload the same exact gif on my own webspace, the gif doesnt work anymore with that code, anyone knows why?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use custom markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820170/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-markers)

Comment: you could link a glitch, i believe if you lose the `preset=custom` attribute it should work if the urls are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom markers in `ar.js` require only to have the `type` and an `url` set:

```
<a-marker type="pattern" url="url/to/mypattern.patt">
  <a-entity myobject></a-entity>
</a-marker>
```

You can check it out in this [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/custommarker-ar) using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkmkk.jpg) image.

Comment: Hey, sorry didn't have time to check it out until now. Taking your code works. Modifying my code with the url to your Pattern works too.
 But when I try to download the pattern and upload it to googledrive or a webspace and link it, it breaks. 
Is there a certain way how to upload patterns or do you have any other idea why that is the case?

Comment: Uploading the pattern to github pages and using that Link seems to work. But I can not think of what is wrong with the webspace, that uploading it there does not work. Anyways custom marker works. Thanks a lot!